# Error importing file .exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have my own Strings.resx file where I keep all my strings data.

This application will be multilingual so I do have other files such as: Strings.sv

Anyways when I add another string and try to build the project I get the following error:

> Error 1   Error importing file
>   'c:\Users\Ванчо\Desktop\Ann\Proekt\CookBookApp\CookBookApp\obj\x86\Debug\CookBookApp.exe'
>   -- The system cannot find the file specified. C:\Users\Ванчо\Desktop\Ann\Proekt\CookBookApp\CookBookApp\ALINK CookBookApp

Where CookBookApp is the name of the project. Here is image that I have captured

I can't upload images yet so this is a URL to dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/16roo6stw2dcs3p/Proket%20problem.png

When I change the text sometimes it continues to build the project but when I use the text you see on the image, the problem appears again and again.
If anybody had any experience with things like this please do share it.

Comment: Do you have a custom build step that is changing the $(OutDir) location?  Have you verified that it is creating an exe of that name at that location?

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for the response, now I don't have a custom build step everything is set to default, and yes I can verify that if not for this error VS is creating the exe in that location.

Comment: Have you tried Cleaning the solution then rebuilding?

Comment: Yes i tried and same result

Comment: can you provide the path of the project?

Comment: Hi Andre, what do you mean by provide the path of the project?

Comment: What is the path which project is located?

Comment: c:\Users\Ванчо\Desktop\Ann\Proekt\ and after that is the solution folder with exe: CookBookApp\CookBookApp\obj\x86\Debug\CookBookApp.exe

Comment: Very obscure.  These kind of errors are almost always caused by virus scanners.  They get way too eager when they see an EXE pop up from no-where.  Disable the scanner or make an exclusion and try again.

Comment: Hans that was the problem, my Anti-Virus made this impossible for me. Please do post this as an answer so that I can make this comment as solution. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I found a very similar question in MSDN forums with an answer. Please, consider following this solution.

The question:

> `"Error    1    Error importing file
>   'g:\Users\go\dev\gc\UniqueRoutesPlugin\obj\Debug\ur.dll' -- Det går
>   inte att komma åt filen eftersom den används av en annan process.
>
>   G:\Users\go\dev\gc\UniqueRoutesPlugin\ALINK    UniqueRoutesPlugin"`

The answer:

> I found the issue: Panda Cloud Antivirus
>
> Replaced it, now it seems to work fine.
>
> Marked as answer by gerhardol Sunday, April 04, 2010 10:46 PM

[click to here to go to MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91b3defe-e7eb-4591-b75e-1e9f86f0848b/alink-error-importing-file)